# Devolopping iOS apps with xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

i want to start a project that consist in mobile apps. can i develope native apps with Xamarin.Forms to the three platforms with a pc (Sony Vaio) and visual studio.

Comment: You can find all necessary informations here -> https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/ and for Xamarin.Forms here -> https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop for Windows (Phone, or better yet Universal Windows Platforms Apps) and Android. They just work with Visual Studio.

If you want to build an iOS app as well, you are going to need a Mac. Building for iOS cannot be done without a Mac. There are a few options:

- Buy a Mac laptop with a Windows VM; this is an option you see for most developers, however it is an expensive one because you're going to want a good MacBook Pro with a 1TB disk.
- Buy a (cheap-ish) Mac (Mini); Xamarin is built so that you can let a standalone Mac machine do all the iOS building. All you have to do is install it with XCode and Xamarin, connect it to your network and you are ready to go. With the new Xamarin [iOS Simulator for Windows](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/) you don't have to look  at your Mac ever again. Let's be clear: the Simulator for Windows isn't a Simulator which runs *on* Windows. It simply mirrors the Simulator from your Mac.
- Rent a Mac in the cloud. There are solutions like [macincloud.com](http://www.macincloud.com/) which let you rent a Mac hosted by them. They have different plans depending on your needs. The concept stays the same; you connect to a Mac in 'your network' (which is now over the internet) to build your iOS app.

Whichever option you choose; you are going to have to spend some extra money on Apple hardware to get to develop your iOS app.